# Generated doctrine entities for specific tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a single Entity from existing database using symfony2 and doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371600/generating-a-single-entity-from-existing-database-using-symfony2-and-doctrine)

I am working on migrating a legacy enterprise app to Symfony2. When it is all done we will have dozens of tables. Each application uses a subset of the tables, and we want to keep the tables in 3 databases, not one database per Symfony bundle.

Is it possible to use the doctrine command line tools to generate metadata and entities for just a subset of the tables in a database? We would like to be able to generate/re-generate the metadata as we develop and tables change, but we don't want to generate the information for all of the tables in the db.

Comment: Hope the following link helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371600/generating-a-single-entity-from-existing-database-using-symfony2-and-doctrine

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I don't know why I couldn't find it on my own. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem Quint you are welcome ;)