# Generate Entities with Doctrine into separate namespace

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, doctrine, entity

I'm following the documentation here:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

These are the commands

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

I see the new Entities here in"

```
Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle/Entity
```

But I wanted to know how I could add the Entities into their own namespace like this

```
Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle/Entity/Foo
Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle/Entity/Bar
```

This is so I could keep the Entities for Foo and Bar Databases separated.

UPDATE:

Or should it be structured like this:

```
Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle/Foo/Entity
Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle/Bar/Entity
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you're asking. You want to create a new namespace for each entity? That makes no sense. Then Foo is /Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle/Entity/Foo/Foo, Bar is /Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle/Entity/Bar/Bar, and they're both the only objects in their own namespace. Is that really what you're looking for?

Comment: I have multiple databases and I would like to organise the Entities by database, So the Foo Database should go into the Foo directory and the Bar database in the Bar directory. This is just to easily identify what database an Entity is related to

Comment: Oh, that's a really interesting problem. I unfortunately have no idea, though :(. My current project also has multiple DBs, but they have the same structure with different data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at [How to work with Multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) section of the documentation, you'll notice that you can bind your bundle entities to one or many [entity managers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). Each one of them related to a specific database connection.

If for example I've defined two database connections (first_connection and second_connection), I can than add two entity managers as follow,

```
entity_managers:
    first_manager:
        connection:       first_connection
        mappings:
            MyBundle:
                dir:      Path/To/EntityFolder/Foo/
    second_manager:
        connection:       second_connection
        mappings:
            MyBundle:
                dir:      Path/To/EntityFolder/Bar/
```

You can then specify the right Entity Manager to use during the two first steps of the [entity generation process](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html),

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force --em=first_manager --filter=MyTable
```

**Note:** The `--filter` option is used to allow you generate your entities individually.

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation --em=first_manager --filter=MyTable

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

Your entities are then put into the right folders according to the connection the were bound to.

Comment: Must have missed this, Thanks

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]                         
  Bundle "dir" does not exist or it is not enabled.

Comment: This works except I have one small issue: --filter=MyTable doesn't work. If I remove the option I get all the tables in the database, if I add the option I get: "No Metadata Classes to process.", Thoughts?

Comment: @Phill, you are correct. I either getting "db does not have mapping information" or I am getting "No Metadata Classes to process." error. See [**this comment for explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371600/generating-a-single-entity-from-existing-database-using-symfony2-and-doctrine/10614792#comment40007517_10614792)