# Doctrine Generate Entities Namespace Issue?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Ok I have one last problem with doctrine:generate:entities command

I run the below command and I get the expected file(s) in

```
/src/MyNamespace/Bundle/MyNamespaceBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm
```

comamnd:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/MyNamespace/Bundle/MyNamespaceBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --em=my_manager --filter=TblReports --verbose
```

I see the `TblReports.orm.yml` file(s) and the first line is:

```
TblReports
```

command: ( should this be annotation instead of yml? )

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyNamespaceBundle yml --em=my_manager --filter=TblReports
```

I run the above command I get the files here

```
/src/MyNamespace/Bundle/MyNamespaceBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/
```

Same name as the first files that were generated from the first command, just in a different location and the first line ( Which I'm assuming is the namespace )

```
TblReports.orm.yml
```

and now the first line is:

```
MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\TblReports
```

but I think it needs to be

```
MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\Reports\TblReports
```

Now I run the last command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyNamespaceBundle --path=src --no-backup
```

I get this error

```
[RuntimeException]                                                    
  Bundle "MyNamespaceBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

If I run the command like this

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyNamespaceBundle:Reports --path=src --no-backup
```

I get this error ( but the namespace looks correct )

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                   
  Namespace "MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\Reports" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

Here is my_manager ( config.yml )

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: my_database
      connections:
        my_database:
          driver:   pdo_pgsql
          port:     5432
          dbname:   tbl_reports
          user:     foo_user
          password: foo_pass
          charset:  UTF8
          mapping_types:
            bit: string

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: my_manager
        entity_managers:
            my_manager:
                connection: my_database
                mappings:
                    MyNamespaceBundle:
                      mapping: true
                      dir: Entity/Reports
```

in config_dev.yml ( I use the dev and prod yml files to control the host(s) I can connect to )

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
      connections:
        my_database:
          host: 172.0.0.1
```

Questions:

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. How can I fix it?

Related Questions:

- [Generate Entities with Doctrine into separate namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629959/generate-entities-with-doctrine-into-separate-namespace)
- [Entity Generation for Single Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732017/entity-generation-for-single-table)

UPDATE #1:

Ok well I ran the second command as `annotation` instead of `yml` and the files were generated in:

```
MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity
```

command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyNamespaceBundle annotation --em=my_manager --filter=TblReports
```

I ran the doctrine:generate:entities ( both ways ) and still got errors. I decided to move the files into this directory

```
MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\Reports
```

I ran the doctrine:generate:entities agin ( both ways ) and still got errors.
I looked at the namespace in the files and saw it was pointing to the work namespace. I updated from:

```
MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\TblReports
```

to

```
MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\Reports\TblReports
```

ran this command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyNamespaceBundle:Reports --path=src --no-backup
```

and in now works

```
Generating entities for namespace "MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\Reports"
```

So I guess question #3 is:

3. How can I get the second command to add the correct namespace on the import?

I tried this but no dice

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyNamespaceBundle:Reports annotation --em=my_manager --filter=TblReports
```

Docs:

- http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Source:

- https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/ImportMappingDoctrineCommand.php
- https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php

Answer (score 0):

Your first line needs to end with a : as in:

```
MyNamespace\Bundle\MyNamespaceBundle\Entity\TblReports: 
  <yml> data.
```

You seem to be mixing annotations with yml.  Pick one and stick with it.  I don't use annotations, so the rest is yml comments.  doctrine:mapping:import/convert with yml option generates yml files puts the yml files in Bundle/Resources/config/doctrine.

The collection of yml files are then used to make your entity classes, and it will put them in the location specified in each yml file, which be default is NamespaceBundle\Entity.

Comment: Thanks, I get that part. How do I change that namespace? From NamespaceBundle\Entity to NamespaceBundle\Another\Namespace\Entity

Comment: Put the doctrine files into the directory associated with that namespace, and generate them there?

Comment: Could you list all three commands? I'm trying your suggestion but all I get are errors. Does the order matter?

Comment: doctrine:mapping:import Bundle yml

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyNamespaceBundle --path=src


But you've done these.  My understanding is that symfony's model is to put your reporting entities in their own bundle, and hence the Entity\Reports directory will cause you trouble