# Modular application in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

Im looking for best practises in modular application in symfony 2. To now, my applications was divided to 2 bundles (front and back bundle). But now, I want to divide my application into more modules. For example one bundle for Users managing, next bundle for Products(included categories), next bundle for Pages managing and so on...

The problem is in entities of each bundle. Exists some way, how to assign entities into its bundle? I mean User entity into User bundle, Products and Categories entities into Products bundle and so on.

**Edit:**

I generate entities using doctrine console. But I didnt find any parameter to generate few entity/ies from my DB. Is this way right? Or I have to write entities manually?

I need somethink like this for reusabling of bundles.

Thank`s for any hints ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are waay overcomplicating things. Something simple as managing an entity should not have a full bundle just for that. It is perfectly fine to have one bundle to house 40+ entities.

What you could use another bundle is like this example:

form bundle that will be used for fancy-looking forms, autocomplete fields, image uploader, image resiser etc. Than from your main application form, you could do something like this:

```
$builder->add("Users", "my_fancy_autocomplete_collection", [
   "type"=>new UserType(),
   "autocomplete_route_name"=>"suggest_users"  // controller route          
]) ;
```

And for display, it could be something like: http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager (the first one I found)

That fancy type must have some DataTransformer that would convert display data into real users fetched from database. It is kinda tricky to learn all these things at once but once you do that, you would be able to use that same bundle in other applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I start a symfony 2 project, here is my logic about bundles :

- Create one bundle for my app (with the CLI of course)
- Create other bundles **if** I can reuse them in other projects

So, as @Zeljko said, think twice about your project's scope to define bundles.

After that it's simple, create your entities inside bundle with correct namespaces (for example : Company\Nomdubundle\Entity).

Comment: I`m sorry, my problem specification was wrong. I edited my question. I know, which bundles I want to separate, but the problem is in entity generator.

Answer (score 0):

I found the soultion here (there is a parameter --filter)
[Generating a single Entity from existing database using symfony2 and doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371600/generating-a-single-entity-from-existing-database-using-symfony2-and-doctrine)

Thanks for hints.