# Create a model from existing table (Symfony3)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

I have an existing table with 5 columns, and I want to generate an Entity without that generates a new migration with new table!

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto generate Doctrine-Entity from existing Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830718/auto-generate-doctrine-entity-from-existing-table)

Answer (score -1):

So, as I mentioned in comment - you just need to follow steps in [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).

This way, for Symfony 3 you need follow this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

This command line tool asks Doctrine to introspect the database and generate the XML metadata files under the `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine` folder of your bundle.

Once the metadata files are generated, you can ask Doctrine to build related entity classes by executing the following command.

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

It will generate Entity classes, and after that you must to remove the XML files, generated by first command.

Comment: Might be worth adding a bit more detail in case someone stumbles across this answer in the future and link has gone dead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22442750)

Comment: @mustaccio, thanks for your notes. Updated the answer.